# Arranging test using specflow

Tags: selenium, specflow

I have a test scenario on specflow like this.

Test Scenario 1
Test Scenario 2
Test Scenario 3

Every time i run my test on visual studio the Test Scenario 1 is the first who run first. I want to arrange my test that the Test Scenario 3 run first before running the Test Scenario 1 and 2.

I tried the ordered on visual studio but no luck.

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? Please read the help topics on how to ask a good question. You need to research your own issue, find code samples, etc. and write your own code to solve the issue. If you do all that and still can't figure it out, then come back and edit your question and add notes from the research you did, the code you have tried, and what the result was... any error messages, etc.

Comment: see this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36720866/how-can-i-run-automated-bdd-ui-tests-using-nunit-and-specflow-in-particular-orde/36721792#36721792